# Error: Cannot find module '../models/User' - Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sapper

I'm importing a module in my Sapper application, but I'm getting the error `Cannot find module '../models/User'`

Imported with `const User = require('../models/User');`

Exported as `module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);`

What am I missing to make this work? The path is correct according to vscode.

[image]

'../models/User.js':

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

EDIT:
I re-created the error by starting a new project with `npx degit "sveltejs/sapper-template#rollup" my-app`.

I'm getting the same error even though the project is new, and I haven't installed any additional dependencies [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/losqYdBAhBv).

The path is correct, as confirmed by vscode

Comment: Why are u doing `module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);`. When you can simply do `module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);`

Comment: It's adapted from a course, but doesn't make a difference. I've tested the suggested format.

Comment: Well if u can post a screenshot of your `file hierarchy` then I can help, as of this point nothing seems wrong.

Comment: Here is a screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/szpGpdRMT

Comment: Depending on what sapper does, I think the problem is just you putting files outside the src-folder. If there is a build-step, other files are probably just ignored. (Haven't used sapper, but I think you can deduce as much from looking at package.json)

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if I place the model file in the src folder.

Comment: Thing is, I can import json files from the same location, but not js for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no much experience with Sapper but as far as I could check the problem is that the actual call is made by `__sapper_/dev/server/server.js` and not the one from your `src` folder. If you use `const User = require('../../../models/User')` it should work but you'll need to deal with this deep relative path.

You gonna need to either export your models folder to a path closer to that file or come up with a function to determine the root path and use as a prefix when requiring your models, like `const User = require(rootPath() + './models/User')`.

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over the string inside `require` it will show the absoloute path of the file you're referencing. Check if module it's requiring exists by doing `ls <path of odule>`

Comment: The path I'm seeing while hovering opens the file I'm trying to access.